# Vue.js, prerender-spa-plugin and AWS Amplify - weird redirect rules behaviour

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-amplify

We're running a Vue.js app on AWS Amplify. This part works beautifully and after running the `yarn build` command the site deploys and works perfectly.

The issue comes in with the use of the prerender-spa-plugin for our SEO efforts. We've built it in and the prerender works as expected and deploys all fine, but when browsing the site you get some strange behaviour depending on what you prerender.

For example - we are seeing the following behaviour:
https://example.com: If I browse to https://example.com I get the pre-rendered page - this works fine.

https://example.com/prerenderedURL: If I browse to this URL I see the pre-rendered page after the homepage flashes, I guess this is to do with how we are loading, so will figure this one out.

https://example.com/thisUrl/IsNotPreRendered. If I browse to this URL and the homepage is pre-rendered then I get a 404 page.

My Redirect Ruleset from AWS Amplify:
[AWS Redirect Ruleset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CogP.png)

Any ideas as to what is happening or how to fix it?

Thanks
Ian